# How to save mp3 file stored on removable SD Card to MediaStore (Android Q)?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, file, storage

I have a function that should add a mp3 file to MediaStore, written to removable SD Card on Android Q. The file works just fine if I access it from File Explorer, but I can't see it on Music App (Samsung Music) in my case.

```
@NonNull
public Uri saveMediaToStore(@NonNull final Context context,File file,FileSong fileSong) throws IOException {

    final ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, fileSong.getName());
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mpeg");
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, file.getCanonicalPath());

    }else {
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DATA, file.getCanonicalPath());
    }


    final ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = null;

    try {
        final Uri contentUri;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY);
        }else{
            contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        }
        uri = resolver.insert(contentUri, values);

        if (uri == null)
            throw new IOException("Failed to create new MediaStore record.");

        try (final OutputStream stream = resolver.openOutputStream(uri)) {
            if (stream == null)
                throw new IOException("Failed to open output stream.");

        }

        return uri;
    }
    catch (IOException e) {

        if (uri != null) {
            // Don't leave an orphan entry in the MediaStore
            resolver.delete(uri, null, null);
        }

        throw e;
    }
}
```

It seems to have added it. But when I look inside Samsung Music, it doesn't play, the path doesn't seem to be correct.

This is how MediaStore saved my path:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBJ3C.jpg

This is how Android System saves the mp3 files if I download/copy a mp3 file inside the removable SD Card:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxWYg.jpg

Is it possible that Samsung Music can read those files and show them from SD Card and I as a developer can't?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The file is already on the device? And then you want to add it to the media store? No you should inform the mediastore about the file. With insert() and an output stream you would make a copy.

Comment: `This is how Android System saves the mp3 files if I download/copy a mp3 file inside the removable SD Card:` You say correct path but paths that start with /SD Cart/ .. do not exist on an Android device. From which app is that screen dump? As a programmer you should be able to tell us the real paths. Also Samsung Music does not tell real paths. What a mess.

Comment: @blackapps The file is already on the SD card. I just want to add it to MediaStore so the music app can read it. I know it doesn't exist, but then how the mp3s are read correctly by the music app? Don't they use the same approach of reading from MediaStore? The screen dump is from Samsung Music app. The real path of the file is : /storage/CEED-A1C2/Music/File.mp3 .

Comment: `The file is already on the SD card.` Ok. The file exists on the sd card. AND `I know it doesn't exist,` ?????????????